# How to stop position: fixed jumps to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am developing hamburger sidebar menu for my website. This my current work.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khug8cs6/)

I just want to stop scrolling when hamburger menu expanded. So I've added `overflow: hidden` to body when menu is expanded. (click toggle for body element  `$('body').toggleClass('scroll-lock');` )

**The problem**

I have tested this in ios both chrome and safari browsers. Seems like `overflow: hidden` not working fine. I have googled and found out that I need to add `position:fixed` also. Used that and working fine. But when I scroll down a bit and click my hamburger menu, it will work but **jumps to top!**

I have googled and tried so many times but didn't work any pure css methods.

```
.scroll-lock{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
```

I have a bit js,jquery knowledge.

But I have an idea. How about using `jquery .scrollTop()` function to archive this? Found this resource [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/FH4hD/)

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this solution help you:

1- change position from fixed to absolute (scroll-lock)

2- change parent position to relative

3- (optional) top:10px;left:10px;(more or less than 10)  (scroll-lock)

Comment: Parent you mean class="nav" this one?

Comment: Sorry for delay, Exactly a higher tag, use a container instead body